# Why I can't properly authorize the user on the site via flask_login

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

Good afternoon.

Faced with the problem of initializing the current user Flask_login. I perform authorization on the website. The page that opens only when logged in opens. In fact, I go in.
When logging in, I create a new element of the UserLogin class.

The main class:
`userlogin = UserLogin().create(user)`

UserLogin class:

```
def create(self, user):
        self.__user = user
        return self
```

The element is created, I can get data from the class (ID and etc). However, when I try to get the class ID inside UserLogin, an error occurs.

```
def get_id(self):
        return str(self.__user[0])
```

For example:

```
mainCursor.execute(f"SELECT Users.UserID FROM Users WHERE Users.IsAdmin = '1' AND Users.UserID = '{self.get_id()}'")
```

Error, can't get ID from get_id().

Well.

When I try to just go to a site while being logged in, I can't get the current user's ID because the program can't identify the current user. But what is strange is that it shows that I am logged in and opens those pages that are only available to authorized users.

The Main class:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(UserID):
    print("load_user")
    return UserLogin().fromDb(UserID, conn)
```

The UserLogin class:

```
   def fromDb(self, user_id, database):
        self.__user = fDataBase.getUser(database, user_id)
        return self
```

FDataBase.getUser:

```
def getUser(connection, user_id):
        try:
            connection.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM Users WHERE UserID = {user_id}")
            res = connection.cursor.fetchone()
            if not res:
                print("Пользователь не найден")
                return False
            return res
        except:
            print("Ошибка получения данных из БД")
        return False
```

The program does not want to see the user_id and pass it to the class, which is why I can't perform actions with the current user. I guess I'm wrong somewhere with the sessions, but I can't know for sure.

Comment: Can you put this code `print(self.__user)` inside the get id function and show the print output so I can see what's inside it.

Comment: @DeadSec 'UserLogin' object has no attribute '_UserLogin__user'

Comment: Have you loaded the user before running the get_id()?

Comment: Yes, I did. In the authorization function, I wrote             
userlogin = UserLogin().create(user)
login_user(userlogin)
After this in function, which calls Profile.html I call get_id() and he wrote me this.

Comment: Everything in the same session?

Comment: Yes. I log in as a user, redirecting to Profile 
@app.route('/profile')
@login_required
def profile():
if UserLogin().get_id():
print("True")
As you can see by login_required I enter the function, check UserLogin().get_id, which specifies
    def get_id(self):
        print(self.__user)
        return str(self.__user[0])
And I get the error that I described earlier in the comments

Comment: One thing I dont understand is wy are you doing this way. Login manager has this all built-in. You can call current_user (I think that's the variable) and it gives all info about the current user.

Comment: hm. I tried using current_user, but my python was breaking ://
Okay Then, it turns out, functions like get_id were meaningless and it was only worth using current_user?

Comment: I'm just trying to get the ID of the users that are linked together in the database and with which I will make requests.

Comment: Wy try to invent the wheel when it has already been invented? Use current_user.id to get the id.

Comment: Oh. Oh. Oh. Yes... My bad.. Idk how, but it works :thinking:
Thank you

Comment: I created an answer with what worked for you just in case someone faces the same problem. And you can accept it if it worked for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using new functions use `current_user.id` to get the ID.

This has already been answered in the comment section but in case someone faces the same problem, here is an answer that should work with `login_manager`

Comment: It's me again, hello. Idk how, but I can't take userID from database. When I want to take id from user I get the exception: 
    return str(self.__user[0])
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
And if I use this:
    return str(self.__user['UserID'] I get the same problem. 
I thied this code: current_user.get_id()
I just can't do anything with my ID, can't get query
Edit: In my case current_user.id() = current_user.get_id()

Comment: dont run it as a function `current_user.id()` run it as a variable `current_user.id` running it as a function returns a Bool and not the actual id.

Comment: Is there any way I can get data about the current user's ID? It needs to get it for SQL queries.

Comment: You're probably not using the login manager as it is supposed to be used. I think you should redo everything login manager-related as well as using SQL ORM.

Comment: And yes you can use current_user.<WHAT YOU WANT> that should work but I don't know how you set it up.